# Conditional insert of line breaks to number sequence (preferably using bash, awk, or sed)

Tags: bash, awk, sed, sh

I'm trying to add line breaks to a text file each time a subsequent number is smaller than the immediately preceding number (e.g. a break between "72.774" and "7.009") in a text file with this structure:

```
7.007 28.929 50.851 72.774 7.009 28.932 50.854 72.777 7.015 32.939 54.862 76.784
```

I want the output to be in this format:

```
7.007 28.929 50.851 72.774  
7.009 28.932 50.854 72.777  
7.015 32.939 54.862 76.784
```

Files do not always have the same number of numerical entries (either in total or before the series begins counting up again) nor are the same number of line breaks required in all text files.

I've been trying to use conditionals in awk or sed but haven't had any luck.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions/solutions.

note: edited to reflect 1st comment.

Comment: Can't you come up with an example that's less than, say, 10 fields that demonstrates your problem so we don't have to wade through all of those fields looking for your key values?

Comment: Welcome to SO:SE. Please post your best attempt (code, result...). See [ask].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be what you want:

```
$ awk -v RS=' ' '{printf "%s%s", (NR>1?($0<p?ORS:OFS):""), $0; p=$0}' file
7.007 28.929 50.851 72.774
7.009 28.932 50.854 72.777
7.015 32.939 54.862 76.784
```

Comment: Well, that's certainly shorter than my solution. :)

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution using `awk`:

```
{
  for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {
    if ($i < last) {
        printf "\n"
        last=-1
    } else if (last > 0) {
        printf " "
    }
    printf "%s", $i
    last = $i
  }
}
END { printf "\n" }
```

Example run:

```
$ awk -f foo.awk bar.txt
7.007 28.929 50.851 72.774 94.696 116.619 138.542 160.464 182.387 204.309 226.232 248.155 270.077 292 313.922 335.845 357.768 379.69 401.613 423.535 445.458 467.381
7.009 28.932 50.854 72.777 94.699 116.622 138.545 160.467 182.39 204.312 226.235 248.158 270.08 292.003 313.925 335.848 357.771 379.693 401.616 423.538 445.461 467.384 489.306
7.015 32.939 54.862 76.784 102.708 124.631 146.553 168.476 190.398 212.321 234.244 260.167 282.09 308.013 333.937 355.86 377.782 403.706
7.005 28.928 50.85 72.773 94.696 116.618 138.541 160.463 186.387 212.311 234.233 256.156 278.079 300.001 321.924 347.847
```

Comment: I took the same approach as you, without the placeholder variable: `awk '{printf "%s", $1; for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s%s", ($(i-1)>$i?"\n":" "), $i; print ""}'`

Answer (score 0):

Another AWK solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS=" "; ORS=" "; prev=-999 } 
     { if ( $1<prev ) { printf "\n%.3f", $1 } 
       else { printf "%.3f ", $1 } prev=$1 
     } 
     END { print }'
```